# What does "He who is unjust, let him be unjust still" mean? Revelation 22:11

Tags: contradiction

Revelation 22:11 "He who is unjust, let him be unjust still; he who is filthy, let him be filthy still; he who is righteous, let him be righteous still; he who is holy, let him be be holy still." NKJV

1. Everything is settled, fixed. It is too late for repentance.

Cambridge commentary: "The time is so short it is too late to change".

2. In the previous verse, v10, the book is not sealed. "Do not seal the words of this book". Final positions have not been fixed and the book is open as it is to be preached. It is to be preached because repentance is still possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technical term for this idea is limited probation and is found in many places, in various form throughout the Bible.  Here is a sample:

- Gen 6:3 - *So the LORD said, “My Spirit will not contend with man forever, for he is mortal; his days shall be 120 years.”*  [God decreed that the the probation of the antediluvian world would be 120 years.]
- Zeph 2:2 - *before the decree takes effect and the day passes like chaff, before the burning anger of the LORD comes upon you, before the Day of the LORD’s anger comes upon you.*
- Isa 55:6 - *Seek the LORD while He may be found; call on Him while He is near.*
- Jer 13:16 (NLT) - *Give glory to the LORD your God before it is too late. Acknowledge him before he brings darkness upon you, causing you to stumble and fall on the darkening mountains. For then, when you look for light, you will find only terrible darkness and gloom.*
- Jer 36:7 (NLT) - *Perhaps even yet they will turn from their evil ways and ask the LORD’s forgiveness before it is too late. For the LORD has threatened them with his terrible anger.”*
- Dan 9:24 - *Seventy weeks are decreed for your people and your holy city to stop their transgression, to put an end to sin, to make atonement for iniquity, to bring in everlasting righteousness, to seal up vision and prophecy, and to anoint the Most Holy Place.*  [Compare Matt 21:43 - Therefore I tell you that the kingdom of God will be taken away from you and given to a people who will produce its fruit.  AND  Matt 23:37, 38 - O Jerusalem, Jerusalem, who kills the prophets and stones those sent to her, how often I have longed to gather your children together, as a hen gathers her chicks under her wings, but you were unwilling! Look, your house is left to you desolate.]
- Heb 9:27 - *Just as man is appointed to die once, and after that to face judgment.*  [All of our probation is limited to our lifetime - when we die our probation is ended.]

In summary, probation is limited and God's asks people to decide.  For most of us, probation is limited by the extend our our lives.  For a few who are still alive to personally see Jesus return, our probation ends at the final judgement and the God says (Rev 22:10-12):

> Then he told me, “Do not seal up the words of prophecy in this book,
> because the time is near. Let the unrighteous continue to be
> unrighteous, and the vile continue to be vile; let the righteous
> continue to practice righteousness, and the holy continue to be holy.
> Behold, I am coming soon, and My reward is with Me, to give to each
> one according to what he has done.

Answer (score 2):

**What does “He who is unjust, let him be unjust still” mean? Revelation 22:11**

It is counsel and warning to all people on the earth.

> Verse 10; "Do not seal the words of this book". Final positions have
> not been fixed and the book is open as it is to be preached. It is to
> be preached because repentance is still possible".

If people want to ignore them let them do so "He who is unjust, let him be unjust still"; it is their choice, if people wallow in filth let them die in filth. The Bible counsels people to seek humility and righteousness, and perhaps you will remain hidden.

Zephaniah 2:3 NET

> 3 Seek the Lord,  All you humble of the [a]earth  Who have practiced
> His [b]ordinances;  Seek righteousness, seek humility.  Perhaps you
> will remain hidden  On the day of the Lord’s anger.

Answer (score 0):

> Revelation 22:11 *He who is unjust, let him be unjust still; he who is filthy, let him be filthy still; he who is righteous, let him be righteous still; he who is holy, let him be holy still.*

This is spoken to the all the world - including God's people.

**To the world,** **'let him be unjust still'**. The time for repentance in this age is almost over - no point in trying to get right with God at the last moment like the thief on the cross. There will be no transformation available to you - you will be judged 'guilty' and have to wait till the next time for transformation (probably after the 2nd resurrection).

**To the church (bride) 'let him be holy still.'** Hang on, your reward and eternal life is almost at hand, Jesus will be here soon!

> Behold, I am coming quickly, and My reward is with Me, to render to every man according to what he has done v12

There are billions who have died and never even heard of Christ - there are those few (by comparison) who perhaps have dallied to respond to whatever call God has made to them and now the time is up, or those who never understood who Jesus was and remained deceived -  the *present* opportunity for salvation is passing or has past.

> But do not let this one fact escape your notice, beloved, that with the Lord one day is like a thousand years, and a thousand years like one day. 9The Lord is not slow about His promise, as some count slowness, but is patient toward you, **not wishing for any to perish but for all to come to repentance**. 1 Pet 3:8

> who desires all men to be saved and to come to the knowledge of the truth. 1 Tim 2:4

> For God did not send His Son into the world to condemn the world, but to save the world through Him. John 3:17

However, in Rev, God's focus is on the righteous - the ones in Christ who have lived faithfully for decades, for eons waiting till this moment of grand and glorious change! Rev 22 is all about the brethren about to join with the firstborn from the dead - Jesus - a time of great celebration.

But we mustn't be so quick to dismiss the immoral and liars etc who are now outside the 'gates' and will not be allowed in. If they have refused Christ - he will refuse them, but they are not abandoned or 'sent to hell' - not yet. These are addressed in other places like;

> The rest of the dead did not come to life until the thousand years were completed Rev 20:5

> they (the now eternal righteous) will be priests of God and of Christ and will reign with Him for a thousand years.

Who will they reign over - not one another, but the alive outside the gates. This is now their only opportunity to truly know and respond to the gracious offer of salvation. Satan is bound and no longer deceiving mankind - the earth is Christs.

The *Book* is still accepting names - probably during the 1000 years. People will probably still die of 'old age', there will be a very different life experience when Jesus is in charge and the wicked deception that has infiltrated every human system is removed. Education, health, medicine, science, politics, religion, history, architecture, engineering will all be totally transformed too - reborn in Christ.

Comment: 2 Peter 3:9 "any" to perish. Any in the the world or any in the church? 1 Tim2:4 "all men" or all types of men of whom [v1] Kings are an example. John 3:17 all the world or worldly people.

Comment: The church is just the ones from the world God has called - He will call all at some time. The church isn't 'special', just blessed to be given the opportunity to choose. All will have an opportunity. Think Israel, it was chosen, but all nations (gentiles) will also have same - just later. All is all - all are sinners - Christ has covered all.

Comment: You say ""He will call all at some time" Mat 22:14 says "many are called". "many" is not necessarily "all".